# How should one set a ruby instance variable to an RxRuby Observable?

Tags: ruby, reactive, rx-ruby

I planning treating incoming data from a tcp port as if it were data from a "view".  I would like to set up a number of RxRuby Observables, then depending on the data I get from the tcp port, select the appropriate Observable and publish something to it by calling the `on_next` method.

The following code works, but seems clumsy. The block passed to the `Rx::Observable.create` just sets an instance variable to the observable passed into it.  It's not a huge amount of boiler plate, but something just does not seem right.  Am I missing something?

```
require 'rx'
class GUIMessagePublisher
  attr_accessor :handshake, :handshake_stream, :remote_button, :remote_button_stream

  def initialize
    self.handshake_stream = Rx::Observable.create { |o| self.handshake = o }
    self.remote_button_stream = Rx::Observable.create { |o| self.remote_button = o }
  end

  def publish_handshake
    handshake.on_next("hello")
  end

  def publish_remote_button
    remote_button.on_next(nil)
  end

end

publisher = GUIMessagePublisher.new
publisher.handshake_stream.subscribe { |m| puts "message = #{m}"}
publisher.remote_button_stream.subscribe { puts "remote button clicked" }
publisher.publish_handshake
publisher.publish_remote_button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more about Rx::Subject, I think this would be the preferred way to handle this

```
require 'rx'
require 'forwardable'
class GUIMessagePublisher
  extend Forwardable
  attr_accessor :handshake_subject, :remote_button_subject
  def_delegator :handshake_subject, :as_observable, :handshake_stream
  def_delegator :remote_button_subject, :as_observable, :remote_button_stream

  def initialize
    self.handshake_subject = Rx::Subject.new 
    self.remote_button_subject = Rx::Subject.new
  end

  def publish_handshake
    handshake_subject.on_next("hello")
  end

  def publish_remote_button
    remote_button_subject.on_next("remote button")
  end

end

publisher = GUIMessagePublisher.new
publisher.handshake_stream.subscribe { |m| puts "message = #{m}"}
publisher.remote_button_stream.subscribe { |m| puts "remote button clicked, message = #{m}" }
publisher.publish_handshake
publisher.publish_remote_button
```

The use of Forwardable is optional.  I could have delegated via methods or even just called `.as_observable` on the exposed subject, but this seems right.